# Convert code to MVVM Pattern

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I want to convert my code to MVVM pattern.

Currently my code is:-

```
    Sub New()

            InitializeComponent()

            AddHandler Me.Closing, AddressOf Main_closing
        End Sub

        Private Sub Main_closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
            Globals.IsBestBillStatementActive = False
            Global.Main.ResetSessionTimeoutTimer()
        End Sub
```

For converting it to MVVM pattern. I have changed the code I have changes in the view as follows:-

Added namespace in view:-

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Added Event

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Please tell what other changes I need to make in View and ViewModel.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

Now you just need to handle the CloseCommand in your ViewModel and when the command is executed call the two lines of code:

```
Globals.IsBestBillStatementActive = False
Global.Main.ResetSessionTimeoutTimer()
```

Comment: Can you please tell what code should I do to handle CloseCommand   in ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to create a Public ICommand Property

```
public ICommand CloseCommand { get; set; }
```

2) Then you need to initialize CloseCommand in the Constructor of your ViewModel

```
CloseCommand = New BaseCommand(OnClose)
```

BaseCommand is an Implementation of ICommand.  Which you can find plenty on the web.

3) Then in OnClose you will do

```
Private Sub OnClose()
    Globals.IsBestBillStatementActive = False
    Global.Main.ResetSessionTimeoutTimer()
End Sub
```